# Laravel: redirect to login page if session not set

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to make a login system in Laravel. I have a login page and a dashboard. Before accessing the dashboard, I want to check if the admin is logged in. Everything works fine but the only problem is if a user try to access the dashboard directly from the URL (like http://localhost/myproject/dashboard), I want the system to check if the session is set or not. If it is set, load the page. If not, redirect it to the login page with a message. I have written the checking code in master.blade.php file to see if session is set or not

This is my Login Page with the form (view):

```
<div class="container">

         @if (session('status'))
         <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
               <i class=""></i> <strong align="center">{{session('status')}}</strong>
               </div>
            @endif

        <form class="form-signin" action="auth_admin" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">admin login</h2>
        <div class="login-wrap">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin_email" placeholder="Email ID" autofocus>

            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="admin_password" placeholder="Password">

            <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

            <label class="checkbox">
                <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> Forgot Password?</a></span>
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit">LOGIN</button>


        </div>

      </form>

    </div>
```

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('webadmin','Admin_controller@index');

Route::get('adminlogin','Admin_controller@admin_login_page');

Route::post('auth_admin','Admin_controller@auth_admin');
```

This is my Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\General_model;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;

use DB;

class Admin_controller extends Controller
{   

    public function index()
    {
      return view('adminpanel.index');
    }


    public function admin_login_page()
    {
     return view('adminpanel.loginpage');   
    }

    public function auth_admin(Request $request)
    {
    $admin_email    = $request->input('admin_email');
    $admin_password = md5($request->input('admin_password'));

    $checklogin = DB::table('admin_login')->select('admin_id','admin_email','admin_name')->where(['admin_email'=>$admin_email,'admin_password'=>$admin_password])->first();

    if(count($checklogin) > 0)
    {
        $request->session()->put('admin_id',$checklogin->admin_id);
        $request->session()->put('admin_name',$checklogin->admin_name);
        $request->session()->put('admin_email',$checklogin->admin_email);

        return redirect()->action('Admin_controller@index');

    } else {
        return redirect()->action('Admin_controller@admin_login_page')->with('status','Incorrect Email ID or Password');
    }

    }
}
```

This is my master.blade.php (view)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  @include('adminpanel.template.header')

    <?php
    if(!Session::has('admin_email') && !Session::has('admin_name')) {
    return Redirect::to('Admin_controller@admin_login_page')->with('status','Please login to continue!');
    }
    ?>

  </head>

  <body>

  <section id="container" class="">

      <!--top bar start-->
      <header class="header white-bg">
      @include('adminpanel.template.top_bar')
      </header>
      <!--top bar end-->


      <!--sidebar start-->
      <aside>
      @include('adminpanel.template.sidebar')    
      </aside>
      <!--sidebar end-->


      <!--main content start-->
      <section id="main-content">
        <section class="wrapper">
        @yield('main_content')        
        </section>
      </section>
      <!--main content end-->



  </section>

  @include('adminpanel.template.footer')

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you put your dashboard route (`Route::get('webadmin','Admin_controller@index');`) using authenticated middleware..?

Comment: I have many other pages in my view which make use of master.blade.php. I thought it is better to check it in master file instead of writing code on every route.

Comment: no, well, although [the official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes) indeed put it to every route. we can do something like explained [in the another section of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#middleware-groups) - `Route::group('middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], function (){/*.. put your routes here ..*/})`. Well, the old docs uses this approach for protecting routes.

Answer (score 1):

add thi method

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware("auth");

}
```

in your controller